# Multiple target audience in one website

Tags: first-impression, multiple-data

I'm working on a webpage for a tourist agency which include different target groups and content:

1. Tours for local people inside the country (Georgians in Georgia)
2. Tours for local people outside the country (Georgians outside Georgia)
3. Tours for foreigners inside the country. (foreigners inside Georgia)

Please take in note that Georgians have their own language, which makes it even harder.

So I need to differ to this audience once they open our webpage. Do you have some experience about how it works when there's a target group choosing an option on the first page? Should there be only a questionnaire for the target group or should there be also some information about the travel agency/ the brand as well?

What is the best way to ask people about their target group in such situations? Would it be nice to Ask them straightforward to choose from options or should there be some questions (3-4) and according to the answers they'll be automatically redirected to their target group content.

I am having some thoughts about this first-page issue because the first page creates the first impression and I don't want to scare people with the questions.

Please, share your thoughts and experiences on this topic and about my fears.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how the culture of Georgia would shape the answer, but I would provide generic information on the landing page and then invite the user to identify which group they belong to.

Use phrasing is from the standpoint of a concierge, and be sure to subtly let them know you are asking about what they are searching for, not personal information about them. Perhaps something like: "Please allow us to tailor your results by telling us a little about what you are seeking." Then I would display 4 buttons, one for each of the 3 target groups and one that allows them browse all options.

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible approach would probably be a combination of your ideas: A landing page with a greeting and three large buttons with brief descriptions of each option in English and Georgian. Additionally, right below those buttons, a wide button with "I'd like help deciding" which leads to the questions you proposed that help lead them to the path that best suits their needs.

You might also be able to [detect the user's language or country from their browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680413/get-visitors-language-country-code-with-javascript-client-side) and route them accordingly (or just highlight your guess at their selection in some way), but of course you'll want to ensure that you make it easy for auto-routed users to switch tracks in case you route them incorrectly.